# Tower of Hanoi (in c) recursion - How does it look in the memory?

Tags: recursion

I can't get my head of how the code compile because of the 2 times we need to call for n-1 to set it as the concept.

**The code:**

```
void tower(int n, char A, char B, char C)
{
    if (n == 0)
        return;
    else
    {
        tower(n - 1, A, C, B);
        printf("Disk %d from %c to %c\n", n, A, B);
        tower(n - 1, C, B, A);
    }
}

int main()
{
    tower(3, 'A', 'B', 'C');
}
```

Can someone help with to understand how it is execute in the compiler/stack for each step?

Hope you guys can help me with that. Thanks!

Comment: Use a debugger that allows you to visualize the call stack/graph. Or draw it out on a piece of paper, pretending that you are executing the code.